# Function call instead of self messaging — When to use what?

Tags: objective-c, c, subroutine

In Objective-C, when I want to call a subroutine, I send a message to an object, like:

`[self mySubroutine:myParameter];`

There is a (negligible?) performance penalty, so I could just use a C-style function call:

`mySubroutine(myParameter);`

The implementation of the latter would then reside outside the class’s `@implementation` context.

Is this a no-no? Is it common? Is there a best-practice on this?

Comment: Calling C functions instead of sending Objective-C messages **just for performance** is... sigh. You might as well just not use Objective-C at all!

Comment: Say, I have a sin_approx() function that calculates a rough estimation of a sin()—good enough for the purpose at hand, but less taxing than sin() performancewise. (Think of realtime sound synthesis on an iPhone, for example.) This is more of an utility function than "sending a message to an object". What's more, if the function should be reusable and not be tied to the class, I can't imagine creating a singleton object of a math utility class, just to do something a little quicker.

Comment: That is a case for functions indeed.

Comment: @BoltClock Conversely, using Objective-C messaging just for the sake of it when there is no meaningful relationship between the function and the class is just as "...sigh".

Comment: @walkytalky: `-(void)agreeWith:(NSString *)user { NSLog(@"@%@: Totally.", user); } [self agreeWith:@"walkytalky"];`

Answer (score 7):

Note that those are not necessarily equivalent. Since `-mySubroutine` is an instance method, it probably needs to access a given instance. In that case, your `mySubroutine()` function should have another parameter for the instance, too.

In general, use a method. If you’re worried about performance,<sup>1</sup> you can always get an `IMP` to the method and use it as a function instead of the standard Objective-C message dispatch infrastructure.

That said, some disadvantages of using functions:

- They cannot be overridden by subclasses;
- There’s no introspection (when using the runtime to obtain a list of methods declared by an Objective-C class, functions aren’t enumerated);
- They cannot be used as accessors/mutators of declared properties;
- They aren’t visible to [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html);
- They cannot be directly used for Objective-C message forwarding;
- They cannot be directly used in the various cases where a Cocoa API expects a selector (e.g. when using `NSTimer`).

Some advantages of using functions:

- They cannot be overridden by subclasses (if you want to prevent this);
- There’s no introspection (if you want to prevent this);
- They can be inlined;
- They can have file scope (`static`), preventing code from other files from accessing them.

<sup>1</sup>When you’ve determined that the message dispatch infrastructure is actually a bottleneck. This does happen; for instance, some Apple audio examples do not use Objective-C for audio processing.

**Edit:** Based on OP’s comment, another advantage of functions is that they aren’t necessarily related to a class. If the computation of an approximate value for the sine of an angle doesn’t depend on an Objective-C instance, there’s no need to make it a method — a function is a better fit.

Comment: Can u explain what is Visible to KVC and introspection?

Comment: @Kris I’ve added a bit about introspection and a link to Apple’s documentation for KVC.

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth using where you have static utility functions, such as in a maths library.

In general though, if you need methods that act on the state of an object, the C approach won't be much use, as you won't have implicit access to `self`, unless you explicitly pass it as a parameter.

You may also run into namespace issues.  With the Objective-C different classes can share method names, with the c approach all your functions will need different signatures.

Personally I would always use objective-c methods, the performance difference will be negligible.